# Change String Date Format : Java

Tags: java, jquery, web-applications

I'm building a web application and using a JQuery. I send a single String date to my servlet. It's format is "MM/dd/yyyy", how to convert this into dd/MM/yyyy?

Is it possible to set today date to datepicker and can be previous dates block?

Comment: which plugin are you using to pick date ?

Comment: Do you want to send it from Java to JavaScript in `dd/MM/yyyy` format? Or send it in `MM/dd/yyyy` format and convert it once you get there?

Comment: create a Date object and you will be able to do all kinds of cool things with them: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: *is it possible to set today date to datepicker and can be previous dates block?*  Yes, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm sending JSP page to Java Servlet i found the solution thank u all

Comment: If your input is a string and your desired output is also a string then you can convert between those formats with a simple regex-based string replace, e.g., in JS: `"MM/dd/yyyy".replace(/^(..)\/(..)\/(....)$/, "$2/$1/$3")`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution using JQuery without using `SimpleDateFormat` or `Date`

```
  $( function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
      minDate: 0
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To format dates using Java 8, you can use a DateTimeFormatter:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse("12/01/2017", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy"));
System.out.println(ld.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")));//prints 01/12/2017
```